# MATLAB to C++: Coder: not consistent array dimension concatenation

Tags: c++, matlab, csv

adapting the code from [this coder-compatible solution to read csv data](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/231663-how-do-i-get-the-user-s-input-in-a-matlab-standalone-executeable) i ran into the following issue during the runtime issue check of Matlab Coder:

```
Error using cat>>check_non_axis_size (line 283)
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cat>>cat_impl (line 102)
check_non_axis_size(isempty, i, sizes{i}, varargin{:});

Error in cat (line 22)
result = cat_impl(@always_isempty_matrix, axis, varargin{:});

Error in readCsv (line 28)
coder.ceval('sscanf', [token, NULL], ['%lf', NULL], coder.wref(result(k)));
```

my adaptation:

```
function result = readCsv(filepath, rows, columns)

NULL = char(0);
fid = fopen(filepath, 'r');
% read entire file into char array
remainder = fread(fid, '*char');

% preallocation for speedup
result = coder.nullcopy(zeros(columns,rows));
k = 1;
while ~isempty(remainder)

    % comma, newline 
    delimiters = [',', char(10)];

    % strtok ignores leading delimiter,
    % returns chars upto, but not including, 
    % the next delimiter
    [token,remainder] = strtok(remainder, delimiters);

    % string to double conversion
    % no need to worry about return type / order
    % since we only look at one token at a time
    if coder.target('MATLAB')
          result(k) = sscanf(token, '%f');
    else
        coder.ceval('sscanf', [token, NULL], ['%lf', NULL], coder.wref(result(k)));
    end
    k = k + 1;
end

% workaround for filling column-major but breaks on single-line csv
result = reshape(result,rows, [])';
disp(k)
fclose(fid);
```

the `.csv` in case is a 200x51 matrix

testing in matlab: works as expected - the `.csv` is read 1:1 as with `csvread()`

the error pops up during code generation, and as far as I understand, an issue with writing the result of `sscanf` into the preallocated `result` array - but only for the c code.

Addendum: a line with only integer values `(1,1,1,...,0)` works fine, a line with actual floats `(6.7308,38.7101,...,40.5999,0)` breaks with the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

```
remainder = fread(f, [1, Inf], '*char');
```

turns out `sizeA` argument is not optional in this case